Alternating current complex resistance
I am preparing for an exam and I am stuck on this task and cannot get any further. I would be very grateful for tips and advice. Thank you in advance.
Here is the task:
Two real coils connected in parallel (Figure 5) take the currents I1=1A and I2= 1.5 A from a direct voltage network with U= 10V and the currents I1 = 0.6 A and I2 = 1.2 A from an alternating voltage network of U= 12V with f= 50 Hz.
a) Calculate the resistances R1 and R2 and the inductances L1 and L2 of the coils!
What values ​​do you get for the apparent resistances Z1 and Z2?
b) Calculate the values ​​for the phase shift angles phi1 and phi2!
c). Draw the quantitative U-I vector diagram and use it to determine the
total phase shift angle and I, the effective value of the total current!
Note;  The voltage U is the reference value and , = 0. The following scales should apply for voltage and current: m = 3 V/cm and m = 0.2 A/cm
d) State the voltage and current time functions u(t), i1(t), i2(t) and i(t)!


What work have you done so far and where did you get stuck?

I stopped at task a.

I have calculated the two real resistances R1 and R2 in the direct current case. But I don't know how to determine the inductances L1 and L2
